# Batching React updates across microtasks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have code that looks something like:

```
// File1
async function fetchData() {
  const data = await fetch(...);
  setState({ data });
  return data;
}

// File2
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const data = await fetchData();
    setState({ data });
  })();
});
```

This triggers 2 React commits in 1 task. This makes my app less than 60FPS. Ideally, I'd like to batch the 2 `setState`s. Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

Pink represents React commits (DOM operations). The browser doesn't have a chance to repaint until the second commit is done. I can give the browser a chance to repaint by adding `await new Promise(succ => setTimeout(succ, 0));` between the `setStates`, but it'll be better if I could batch the commits.

It's also pretty much impossible to refactor this, since the `useState` exists in separate files.

I tried `unstable_batchedUpdates` but it doesn't work with async.

Comment: May be silly question since I've zero context, but why are you storing the same "state" data in two components/locations?

Comment: Imo it's irrelevant to the question, but one's a normalized store of all the entities in the app and the other is a view with pagination, sorting, etc.

Comment: React already batches simultaneous state updates AFAIK. To figure out why that doesn't happen in your case, we need to see a [mcve]. Currently we have no idea how you've implemented the state or when/what you're rendering

Comment: @TJ by default there's no batching, batching only occurs with unstable_batchedUpdates and specific conditions like event handlers

Comment: ...just wondering if microtasks implementation has been standardized in all browsers: [Tasks, microtasks, queues and schedules](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/)

Answer (score 0):

You can group fetchData, when fetchData is called with the same argument the cache is checked for a promise and that promise is returned instead of creating a new one (make a new fetch).

When the promise resolves then that cache entry is removed so when component mounts again it will fetch again. To change this behaviour you can pass a different cache object to the group funciton.

```js
//group function (will always return promise)
const createGroup = (cache) => (
  fn,
  getKey = (...x) => JSON.stringify(x)
) => (...args) => {
  const key = getKey(args);
  let result = cache.get(key);
  if (result) {
    return result;
  }
  //no cache
  result = Promise.resolve(fn.apply(null, args)).then(
    (r) => {
      cache.resolved(key); //tell cache promise is done
      return r;
    },
    (e) => {
      cache.resolve(key); //tell cache promise is done
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
  );
  cache.set(key, result);
  return result;
};
//cache that removes cache entry after resolve
const createCache = (cache = new Map()) => {
  return {
    get: (key) => cache.get(key),
    set: (key, value) => cache.set(key, value),
    //remove cache key when resolved
    resolved: (key) => cache.delete(key),
    //to keep cache:
    //resolved: () => 'NO_OP',
  };
};

//fetch data function
const fetchData = (...args) => {
  console.log('fetch data called with', args);
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(args), 1000)
  );
};
//grouped fetch data
const groupedFetchData = createGroup(createCache())(
  fetchData
);
groupedFetchData(1, 2, 3).then((resolve) =>
  console.log('resolved with:', resolve)
);
groupedFetchData(1, 2, 3).then((resolve) =>
  console.log('resolved with:', resolve)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to so something along the lines of this, the aim being to cache the calls for a certain amount of time and then pass them all to `unstable_batchedUpdates` at once.

```
import { unstable_batchedUpdates } from 'reactDOM'
import raf from 'raf'

const cache = []
let rafId = null

function setBatchedState(setState, data) {
  cache.push({ setState, data })

  if(!rafId) {
    rafId = raf(() => {
      unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
        cache.forEach(({setState, data}) => setState(data))
      })

      rafId = null
      cache = []
    })
  }
}

export default setBatchedState
```

This is using `requestAnimationFrame` to debounce the calls to `unstable_batchedUpdates`, you may prefer to use `setTimeout` depending on your use case.